# control an arraylist based on time

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking to use Javascript to make a small web app. I'm trying to find where to start.

What I'm looking to do is control a list of items ie:

item1 
item2 
item3

I want the list to move in a loop based on each day passing. So after Midnight the script would move things to:

item3 
item1 
item2

and so on each successive day.

Is this possible with just Javascript using simple if else statements. I'm new to Javascript and trying to see where I should start.

Thanks.

Comment: `array.unshift(array.pop());` ?

Comment: `javascript` is totally different with `java`

Comment: @Carth yes, sorry for the typo!

Comment: Welcome to SO - If you're just getting started in Javascript and are interested in doing something like what you mention above perhaps this would be helpful reading (stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/…). If your question is simply "Is this possible" then the answer is "yes." If you're looking for a complete example of how to do it then the normal response will be "give it a shot, show us your code and how you're running into trouble, and we'll help."

Comment: You might also want to look into cron jobs on Linux server or task manager on windows server.

Answer (score 0):

use a timeout to act with any time you start the counter and an interval to call the switch function every day!

```
var arr = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

function switchItem() {
   var d = new Date();
   var DC = 1000*3600*24;
   var h = d.getHours(),
       m = d.getMinutes(),
       s = d.getSeconds();
   setTimout(function() {
       setInterval(function(){
          arr.unshift(arr.pop());
       }, DC)
   }, (h*60*60+m*60+s)*1000)
}
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks guys. I will try this out and research further from here. Huge help. Take care.